# FATAL EXCEPTION:main error

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Here is the log message

```
03-07 22:54:51.555: E/AndroidRuntime(18687): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-07 22:54:51.555: E/AndroidRuntime(18687): Process: com.example.simplegamer003.registerapp, PID: 18687
03-07 22:54:51.555: E/AndroidRuntime(18687): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.simplegamer003.registerapp/com.example.simplegamer003.registerapp.SpinnerActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.Spinner
03-07 22:54:51.555: E/AndroidRuntime(18687):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2450)
03-07 22:54:51.555: E/AndroidRuntime(18687):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520)
03-07 22:54:51.555: E/AndroidRuntime(18687):    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
03-07 22:54:51.555: E/AndroidRuntime(18687):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
03-07 22:54:51.555: E/AndroidRuntime(18687):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-07 22:54:51.555: E/AndroidRuntime(18687):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
03-07 22:54:51.555: E/AndroidRuntime(18687):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466)
03-07 22:54:51.555: E/AndroidRuntime(18687):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-07 22:54:51.555: E/AndroidRuntime(18687):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
03-07 22:54:51.555: E/AndroidRuntime(18687):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
03-07 22:54:51.555: E/AndroidRuntime(18687): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.Spinner
03-07 22:54:51.555: E/AndroidRuntime(18687):    at com.example.simplegamer003.registerapp.SpinnerActivity.onCreate(SpinnerActivity.java:22)
03-07 22:54:51.555: E/AndroidRuntime(18687):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
03-07 22:54:51.555: E/AndroidRuntime(18687):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
03-07 22:54:51.555: E/AndroidRuntime(18687):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
03-07 22:54:51.555: E/AndroidRuntime(18687):    ... 9 more
```

and here is my code

```
public class SpinnerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

private Spinner spinner;
private static final String[] sports = {
        "Hockey","Cricket","Football","Basketball","Badminton","Tennis"
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_spinner);

    spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,sports);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
}
}
```

I don't know why am I getting this error please anyone tell me.

Comment: `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.Spinner`

Answer (score 1):

Well, obviously

`java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.Spinner`

Means that you have a LinearLayout instead of `Spinner` with id `"@+id/spinner` in `activity_spinner`

Comment: thnx i gave view's id rather than spinners

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that it is spinner and you have recently made change to your layout file then just clean your project and run again will solve your problem.
Sometimes modifying the layout file will not instantly reflect to R file and gives ClassCastException.

Answer (score 0):

In your SpinnerActivity,LinearLayout can not be cast Spinner.Which means you wirte LinearLayout in *activity_spinner.xml* but use  `spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);` instead .